# Why does this script cause a SQL deadlock often?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dapper, database-deadlocks

I am running a background task within a web job in Azure every hour. Sometimes (it appears to be a little more than 50% of the time, the code will choke (with a deadlock error) on this particular piece of code:

```
foreach (var ownerToProcess in activeOwnersWithMessageArchiving)
{
    foreach (var extension in extensions)
    {
        using (var db = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            db.Execute(@"
UPDATE T_MESSAGESTARTER 
   SET Started=@started,Completed=NULL 
 WHERE OwnerId=@ownerId AND ExtensionId=@extensionId;

if @@ROWCOUNT=0
  INSERT INTO T_MESSAGESTARTER (OwnerId,ExtensionId,Started) 
  VALUES (@ownerId,@extensionId,@started)
", new { ownerId = ownerToProcess, extensionId = extension, started = DateTimeOffset.Now });
        }
    }
}
```

It's a simple update/insert statement. I "believe" I am using row-level blocking too. This is not inside a transaction. Also, there are around 60 `ownerToProcess` items in the top-level. And each one of those has between 5-60 `extension` items in the inner loop (in the code above). And that makes for around 4000 executions of this SQL statement throughout each run. Each `@owner`/`@extension` combo (in the WHERE clause) is unique.

Sometimes it will run all the way through without errors. But sometimes I will get the deadlock error on one of the executions of the SQL statement. What could be causing this? Is it because I have the `UPDATE/INSERT` structure in the SQL statement? Or could Dapper be doing something funny?

Another thing to note: the `T_MESSAGESTARTER` table in question does not have a primary key. Could that be causing this issue?

Comment: We need to see your deadlock graph to know what resources are deadlocking and why. Its not something that can be determined just from the code.

Comment: SUGGESTION: Consider moving these two lines into a stored procedure, and enable `AUTOCOMMIT_SP_MODE=ON` within the stored procedure.  I'll bet there's a very good chance it could eliminate the deadlocks.  Easy to do; easy to empirically verify ;)

Comment: @DaleK I'm not a SQL expert and I don't know how to generate a deadlock graph unfortunately.

Comment: @MattSpinks if you google obtaining a deadlock graph you'll find there is a fairly straight forward query to obtain it - I just don't have it on me.

Comment: OK found one https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/01/09/sql-server-get-historical-deadlock-information-system-health-extended-events/

Comment: I am not familiar with Azure programming, but surely one shouldn't put opening a new SQL connection inside a loop (and a double loop at that)?

Answer (score 1):

the update locks the "table" even if no row is actually updated (when row does not exist). 
Depending on the concurrency the following most likely is safe (if two processes will never handle the same owner&extension then it will work)

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT ...  FROM T_MESSAGESTARTER WHERE OwnerId=@ownerId....)
BEGIN
UPDATE T_MESSAGESTARTER 
   SET Started=@started,Completed=NULL 
 WHERE OwnerId=@ownerId AND ExtensionId=@extensionId;
END
ELSE 
  INSERT INTO T_MESSAGESTARTER (OwnerId,ExtensionId,Started) 
  VALUES (@ownerId,@extensionId,@started)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need to be the PK but a composite unique index on ownerId and extensionId, ideally clustered, will optimize the update query. That might mitigate deadlocks (depending on the processes involved) by touching the minimal amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

No need to open a connection in a double foreach iteration.

```
using (var db = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
  foreach (var ownerToProcess in activeOwnersWithMessageArchiving)
  {
    foreach (var extension in extensions)
    {

            db.Execute(@"
UPDATE T_MESSAGESTARTER 
   SET Started=@started,Completed=NULL 
 WHERE OwnerId=@ownerId AND ExtensionId=@extensionId;

if @@ROWCOUNT=0
  INSERT INTO T_MESSAGESTARTER (OwnerId,ExtensionId,Started) 
  VALUES (@ownerId,@extensionId,@started)
", new { ownerId = ownerToProcess, extensionId = extension, started = DateTimeOffset.Now });
    }
  }
}
```

And FYI, there exists also the [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql) statement.
Which is a standard SQL that can also do upserts.